# How To Know When A FileSystemWatcher Is Finished

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, filesystemwatcher

So below is how I'm using the FileSystemWatcher to move PDFs from one location to another.

```
Public Sub WATCHER()

    'CREATE NEW FILESYSTEMWATCHER
    Dim Watcher As New FileSystemWatcher()
    Watcher.Path = "<<path>>"
    Watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite
    Watcher.Filter = "*.pdf"

    AddHandler Watcher.Changed, AddressOf OnChanged
    AddHandler Watcher.Created, AddressOf OnChanged

    Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub OnChanged(source As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)

    'MOVE PDFs TO NEW LOCATION
    For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("<<path>>", FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.pdf")
        Dim foundFileInfo As New System.IO.FileInfo(foundFile)
        'ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Moving PDFs..."
        File.Move(foundFile, "<<path>>" & foundFileInfo.Name) 'MOVES PDFs
    Next

End Sub
```

I want to continue with something only after all PDFs are moved, say a msgbox stating all files have been moved. Is there some event that is raised when the moving is complete?

Comment: a filewatcher is never actually finished or the work complete until the app ends is it?  Isnt that the point of a watcher?

Comment: my thought is you can start a watcher at any point correct? i also thought you could stop it at any point without having to close the app. if i knew everything about a file watcher i wouldn't have asked a question though and since i obviously didn't know everything about it i got down voted, nice huh?

Comment: yes, you can start and stop them, but as long as they are running they are never finished.  You probably want some sort of progress report like a label indicating the last move, but you will have to contend with cross thread calls.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that File.Move is a synchronous method. After the for loop you can message the user that everything has been moved.  The File.Move does not take very long to execute because its not moving anything around on the disk, it only updates the files path.  If you swap File.Move out with File.Copy, you should see a greater delay before it messages the user that everything has finished.

Comment: That was my thinking as well. I tested this and it only moved 2 files, threw the msgbox, stopped moving the files all together. I tested this with about 1,500 PDF files.

Comment: were you trying to move files that were all in the same directory or did you have some files that were in sub directories?

Comment: well originally i had the file move in the completed event on my backgrounder, which locked the app when the move took place. i was given a suggestion to use the filesystemwatcher, which works well. also, these pdfs are being generated from another process, so they aren't all generated at the same time.

Comment: hmm, well maybe from the process that is in charge of moving the files you could call Function MoveMyFiles(FromPath,ToPath) As Integer, which would move everything in that folder and return the number of files moved.  Keep calling MoveMyFiles until it returns 0. Then you could wait x amount of time and call MoveMyFiles again. If it returns 0 again then assume that the other process has finished.

Comment: other than that it seems like you would need some flag raised from the other process letting you know that it has finished creating the pdf files, at which point you would just call MoveMyFiles once.